# Conan Exiles - Win and End the Game? Or Perpetual Survival?

Tags: conan-exiles

I've been playing Conan Exiles on a friend's server for a couple of weeks now, and it just hit me................is this one of those "endless treadmill" games of perpetual survival, or is there an actual endpoint? A goal to strive for?

Is there something that you can find to escape the wilderness, or remove that bracelet without dying?

I've been having fun building a massive compound/fortress to use as my base of operations, but I figure this is a waste of time if there's an end-goal I should be focusing on instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a final goal in Conan Exiles, which is to remove the bracelet and escape the exile lands: 
https://conanexiles.gamepedia.com/The_Exiles_Journey#Escape_the_Exiled_Lands

> But this will basically delete your character and end the game.